# How to access log output from real windows phone 8 device

Tags: logging, windows-phone-8, error-log

I have to get access to a crash log on a windows phone 8 device.

I just deployed the XAP file there and it was successfully installed but seem to crash on startup.

I just started with wp8 development and looking for something similar like logcat for android.

Any tips for me to get the information? All my search revealed only information for output of debug-run...

I have Visual Studio 2012 Express, if this helps...

Comment: There isn't a built-in crash log for wp apps unless it is published in the store where you can access these logs of your registered apps.

Comment: You will need the original code unless the original developer has implemented crash log reports to be sent through email or uploaded somewhere.

Comment: ok thanks. Make that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a built-in crash log for wp apps unless it is published in the store where you can access these logs for your registered apps.

You will need the original code unless the original developer has implemented crash log reports to be sent through email or uploaded somewhere.

Note, if you deployed through the xap deployment tool you can check `IsolatedStorage` for the app using a tool like [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/). Maybe the original developer logs unhandled exceptions there.