# Debugging IBM Application Center Issues

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

Can anyone suggest how to resolve issues on IBM Application center, I am not able to login and download the apps, I am getting a alert message "server error - contact the server administrator", is there a way to debug things and see what is happening, Please suggest.

Thanks
djrecker

Comment: I'd check the AppCenter logs first.

Comment: Can you please suggest how would you do that, As i have downlaod the app center on device and cannot see any logs from xcode organizer console. Please let me know if you ahve a different approach for viewing the logs.

Comment: I thought you are referring to the server AppCenter. For mobile: check if server is reachable; check server logs to see if a request is being made; check if AppCenter app creates a log locally - there's the iTools (not from IBM) tool that can browse the installed app directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the message "server error", most likely you will see something in the webserver logs. The webserver logs are in

- <Tomcat>/logs
- <Liberty>/usr/servers/<yourserver>/logs
- <WAS>/profiles/<yourprofile>/logs  (and its subdirectories)

If you use firewalls, IHS, load balancers etc., you should also check their logs, as the error can be there.

Device logs can be obtained from the device:

For iOS:

- Download iPhone Configuration Utility from Apple to your computer.
- Exit iTunes and Xcode before using.
- Open iPhone Configuration Utility
- Connect Device

For Android:

- See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882253/how-do-i-get-the-logfile-from-an-android-device)

For BlackBerry until version 6:

- The log file can be downloaded from a USB-connected device with the JavaLoader.exe.  (Command: JavaLoader.exe eventlog).

For Windows Phone 8, the situation is not optimal:

- See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938490/how-to-access-log-output-from-real-windows-phone-8-device)

In those logs, you should see all REST communication (URLs) that is happening between the device and the webserver. I think a server error is most likely a REST Response 500 "Internal server error", which means there was an exception in the server that you should see in the server logs (or firewall logs etc).